# Unexpected c pointer result

Tags: c, pointers

Hi I have recently started learning c pointers and can't understand why am i getting a different pointer value than expected. 
Here is the function

```
int test(void){
    int i,j; 
    int **p = (int **)malloc(2 * sizeof(int *)); 
    p[0] = (int *)malloc(2 * sizeof(int)); 
    printf("p[0] = %d\n",p[0]);
    p[1] = p[0]; 
    printf("p[1] = %d\n",p[1]);
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){ 
            for(j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                    p[i][j] = i + j;
                    printf("p[%d][%d] = %d\n",i,j,p[i][j]);
            }
    } 
    printf("result p[0][0] = %d\n",p[0][0]); 
 return 0;
}
```

I am expecting p[0][0] = 0 as printed from the for loop, however it is equal to 1 and the value seems to be coming from p[1][0], what am i missing here?

printf output:

```
p[0] = 1224416
p[1] = 1224416
p[0][0] = 0
p[0][1] = 1
p[1][0] = 1
p[1][1] = 2
result p[0][0] = 1
```

Comment: You're missing the fact you've got this in your code: `p[1] = p[0];`

Comment: `p[1] = p[0];` <- this assigns pointers ...

Comment: Aside: please print a pointer like this: `printf("p[0] = %p\n", (void*)p[0]);`

Comment: That is not your actual code. The newline is incorrect `/n` ==> `\n`.

Comment: @Ron depends. In the question's code: yes. There's no need to use pointers like this in C++ **at all**. But there's a need for `malloc()` in C++: interfacing with C.

Comment: @FelixPalmen That is correct. WinAPI comes to mind.

Comment: It is because you *print* the result of each element's assignment *before* you overwrite it in a following iteration.

Comment: This is C, not C++.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs if OP uses C++, it doesn't matter whether it's a "good idea" to write such code in C++. It's still C++.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs The OP said they were using C++ and `int **p = (int **)malloc(2 * sizeof(int *));` is the C++ way to use `malloc` so I would stick with C++ unless the OP says otherwise.

Comment: the example i'm using coming from the cppinstitute.org CLA course chapter 5 test

Comment: @anonymous007 if they are presenting that in a C++ course you should consider to not continue that course. _CLA: Programming Essentials in C_ So it looks like it's a C course.

Comment: they are presenting a course in C language

Comment: Then why do you use the C++ tag instead of the C tag?

Comment: I don't know differences between c and c++ however from the discussions above can tell there is a lot of difference :D

Comment: @anonymous007 yes there is. If this is supposed to be C, by all means use a C compiler (and do the tag edits yourself). Then you can remove the redundant (in C, not in C++) casts on the `malloc()` calls.

Comment: Is visual studio 2017 community is good to use to compile c code? or is it supposed to be used with c++?

Comment: @anonymous007 there's a C compiler coming with it, but it only fully conforms to C89 with **most** of C99, so very outdated. For windows, you might want to use MinGW, easily installable e.g. using [MSYS2](http://www.msys2.org/). AFAIK, it can be used with visual studio as well.

Answer (score 5):

First -- You are passing `int*` to `printf()`, which expects `int` (`%d`) , use (`%p`) for printing address instead.

---

Second --

```
p[1] = p[0];
```

The `p[0]` and `p[1]` pointers are both pointing to same address. Which means if you modify one row (`p[0]`), second (`p[1]`) will be modified as well.

And this is root of your problem

> I am expecting p[0][0] = 0 as printed from the for loop, however it is
>   equal to 1 and the value seems to be coming from p[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)[0], what am i
>   missing here?

```
+---+---+
| 0 | 0 |
+---+---+
 ^ ^
 | |
 | -------------------- p[0]
 ---------------------- p[1]
```

Now you modify `p[1]`, and it looks like this. In other words, values `0` and `1` of `p[0]` are overwritten

```
+---+---+
| 1 | 2 |
+---+---+
 ^ ^
 | |
 | -------------------- p[0]
 ---------------------- p[1]
```

Instead of `p[1] = p[0]`, assign to `p[1]` (different) memory on heap as well.

```
p[0] = malloc(2 * sizeof(int)); 
p[1] = malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
```

And now `p[0][0]` is correctly `0`.

---

Third -- recasting malloc is redundant and may lead to problems. [Do i cast malloc return value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

---

In `C++` you can(*should*) use built in operators `new` and `delete`.

Also dont forget to `free()` your allocated memory on heap.

Answer (score 0):

Breaking it down line by line:

```
int **p = (int **)malloc(2 * sizeof(int *));
```

After this line executes, you have the following:

```
   +---+                +---+
p: |   | --------> [0]: |   | ---?
   +---+                +---+
                   [1]: |   | ---?
                        +---+
```

`?` indicates that `p[0]` and `p[1]` contain *indeterminate* pointer values (`malloc` does not initialize the memory it allocates); these pointer value are most likely not valid (i.e., do not correspond to the address of an object in your program).

```
p[0] = (int *)malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
```

After this line executes, you have the following:

```
   +---+                +---+              +---+
p: |   | --------> [0]: |   | ------> [0]: | ? |
   +---+                +---+              +---+
                   [1]: |   | ---?    [1]: | ? |
                        +---+              +---+
```

Again, `?` represents an indeterminate value.

```
p[1] = p[0];
```

After this line executes, you have the following:

```
   +---+                +---+              +---+
p: |   | --------> [0]: |   | ---+--> [0]: | ? |
   +---+                +---+    |         +---+
                   [1]: |   | ---+    [1]: | ? |
                        +---+              +---+
```

Now, `p[0]` and `p[1]` are pointing to the same block of memory.  Thus, `p[0][0]` and `p[1][0]` resolve to the *same object*.  If we unroll your loop, we see the following sequence of assignments:

```
p[0][0] = 0 + 0;

   +---+                +---+              +---+
p: |   | --------> [0]: |   | ---+--> [0]: | 0 |
   +---+                +---+    |         +---+
                   [1]: |   | ---+    [1]: | ? |
                        +---+              +---+

p[0][1] = 0 + 1;

   +---+                +---+              +---+
p: |   | --------> [0]: |   | ---+--> [0]: | 0 |
   +---+                +---+    |         +---+
                   [1]: |   | ---+    [1]: | 1 |
                        +---+              +---+

p[1][0] = 1 + 0;

   +---+                +---+              +---+
p: |   | --------> [0]: |   | ---+--> [0]: | 1 |
   +---+                +---+    |         +---+
                   [1]: |   | ---+    [1]: | 1 |
                        +---+              +---+

p[1][1] = 1 + 1;

   +---+                +---+              +---+
p: |   | --------> [0]: |   | ---+--> [0]: | 1 |
   +---+                +---+    |         +---+
                   [1]: |   | ---+    [1]: | 2 |
                        +---+              +---+
```

This is why you're seeing the ouput you're seeing.  The fact that `p[0]` and `p[1]` show the same value in your output should have been a big hint.

If `p[1]` is meant to point to a different array from `p[0]`, then you'll need to allocate *another* block of memory for `p[1]` to point to:

```
p[1] = malloc( 2 * sizeof *p[1] );
```

As a matter of practice, you'll want to explicitly `free` everything you allocate, even if your program is about to exit - it's just a good habit to get into:

```
free( p[0] ); // free each p[i] *before* freeing p
free( p[1] ); // assuming you added the malloc for p[1]
free( p );
```

---

If this is meant to be C code, lose the cast on the `malloc` calls - it's unnecessary, it just adds visual clutter, and under C89 could mask a bug if you forgot to include `stdlib.h`.  A much better way to write those calls is

```
int **p = malloc( 2 * sizeof *p );
```

and

```
p[0] = malloc( 2 * sizeof *p[0] );
```

If this is meant to be C++ code, use `new` and `delete` instead of `malloc` and `free`.

Answer (score -1):

I'm answering my own question as it is getting a lot of irrelevant discussions.

as i have
pointed row 1 to share the same allocated memory with row 2
here -> p[1] = p[0]; 
the "for" loop overwrites the values in the first row with values from the second row.

The example function is coming from the cppinstitute.org CLA course chapter 5. Hope this will give a little more clarity to somebody like me in the future.

Comment: Its not _"irrelevant discussions"_. We are just giving you more advices what are you doing wrong.

Comment: You just completely do not understand pointers. Start from something easier just the basics - then progress to the more complicated problems etc etc. I do not think that anyone can explain it to you as you do not have the basic knowledge (you have missed several lessons before this one).

Comment: @PeterJ I do not agree with you. Even though i'm still learning the pointers. But never mind.

Comment: @anonymous007 there is nothing to agree. It is obvious. less YT more books - my advice